# Android - empty items added to the listview?

Tags: android, listview, items

I am trying to add running tasks to the `ListView`.

When i am adding first time using function called `loadTasks()`. it's added perfectly.
But when i am trying to reload it, as i am refreshing the task list after every 10 seconds, its adding two or more empty items in my list.

Comment: private String[] SystemProcessList = {"system", "com.android.phone", "com.android.voicedialer", "com.android.mms", "com.android.media", "com.android.calendar", "com.android.alarmclock", "com.android.inputmethod", "android.process", "com.google.process", ":"};

this is systemprocesslist which i am using to avoid system processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for reload the list

```
private Handler meethandler=new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomeScreen.this,android.R.layout.test_list_item, mMeeting);
            mMeetinglist.setAdapter(aa);
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mMeetinglist.invalidate();              
        }

    };
```

when you want update the list call the handler like this

```
meethandler.sendemptymessage(0);
```